# Tkinter trouble with strings

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to design a basic app which is able to match an input word to words from books in a database. However when I run the following code which is part of a function that is fed into the output of the there are never any matches.

```
  relevant_books = ''
  
  if any(str(input.get('1.0', 'end')) in w for w in book_database[i]) ==True:
        
        relevant_books += book_database[i]
```

I have tried various different methods of string matching but none of them work. I think its because there is something different about tkinter inputs to regular strings?

Comment: maybe write it as normal for-loop - and then you can add `print()` to see what you have in variables.

Comment: maybe you check wrong relation  - maybe you should check `w in ...` instead of `... in w`.

Comment: I also tried this for loop:

Comment: We need to know what `book_database` and `i` are. It appears that you are trying to do a list comprehension on a list item, which won't work. Also the list comprehension isn't enclosed in `[]`, so you'll have a Syntax Error.

Comment: for i in range(len(book_database)):
        if isWordPresent(book_database[i], str(comp_name.get('1.0', 'end')) ) == True:
       
        
            relevant_books += book_database[i]

Comment: we can't run your code, and we don't know what you have in `input.get()` and in `book_database[i]` so we have no idea why it doesn't work. Better create minimal working code with example data.

Comment: This is an example output from the code, I reduced the problem to sentences and not books

Comment: Please try to edit the question to have a [Minimum Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your code.

Comment: ['THERANOS', 'INC.,', 'A', 'CONSUMER', 'HEALTHCARE', 'TECHNOLOGY', 'STARTUP,', 'WAS', 'ONCE', 'VALUED', 'AT', '$10', 'BILLION,', 'AND', 'ITS', 'LEADERSHIP', 'CLAIMED', 'IT', 'WOULD', 'REVOLUTIONIZE', 'THE', 'BLOOD-TESTING', 'INDUSTRY.']
THERANOS

Comment: The top line is the sentence that i print in list form and the line under is the word im interested in, there is clearly a match here but code isnt showing it

Comment: first you could run normal loop `for w in book_database[i]: print(w, input.get('1.0', 'end'), input.get('1.0', 'end') in w)` to see if it compares correct values.

Comment: This is the output O THERANOS
 False
n THERANOS
 False
  THERANOS
 False
J THERANOS
 False
a THERANOS
 False

Comment: All iterations give false

Comment: but your iterations show that you compare wrong values - your `w` doesn't have word but single char - it seems you iterate chars instead of words - so maybe you should use `book_database` instead of `book_database[i]`. You could first use `print()` to see what you really have in `print( book_database[i] )`

Comment: This is the new output, your right it is now comparing sentences

Comment: "What Is Theranos?"  Theranos
 False

Comment: "On Jan. 3, 2022, Theranos founder Elizabeth Holmes was found guilty of four out of 11 fraud charges.   "          Theranos
                                     False

Comment: Are you aware that `input.get('1.0', 'end')` returns a string that ends with a newline?

Comment: is there any operation I could do to remove the newline

Comment: This has solved it thanks so much Bryan!

Answer (score 1):

The text widget automatically adds a newline to the very end of the data in the widget. When you call `input.get('1.0', 'end')` you're going to get a string that includes this trailing newline.

To get all of the data except for this trailing newline use `input.get('1.0', 'end-1c')`. The `-1c` means to get the data all of the way to the end minus one character.

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need the `== True` part. any returns `True` or `False` and thats enough for the `if` condition.
2. i think you have an issue with your list comprehension. `w for w in book_database[i]` should be encapsulated with square brackets `[`

Comment: Doesnt run when u apply 2.

Comment: 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: well, what are you trying to iterate over? there are too many unknown variables. what is `book_database[i]`? list a single value?

Comment: It is just a sentence

Comment: Please try to edit the question to have a Minimum Reproducible Example in your code.